# Como colocar menu no longclick?

Tags: android, listview

Gostária de saber, como colocar aquelas opções de editar e deletar quando executamos o LongCLick do listview .Se for possível pelo menos me informar o nome ou dar um exemplo, eu agradeço.

Comment: Podes usar o ContextMenu

Comment: Ou seria o **ActionMode**?

Comment: @Wakim eu uso ContextMenu e fica impecável.

Comment: veja se isso ajuda! http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu